Ck Editor TABLE'S CONFIGURATION
when I use the editor to create tables, the 'figure class="table"' tag is automatically added which creates problems with the table graphics;
How do I deactivate it?
I tried disabling the figure tag, plugins for media and images and the use of classes:
      allow: [
        {
          name: /.*/,
          attributes: true,
          classes: false,
          styles: true,
        },
      ],

removePlugins: ["Image", "MediaEmbed"],

 disallowedContent: {
    name: /.*/,
    classes: true, 
  },

